# Safari, Angular 15, and HTML Videos - Will not Autoplay in Safari

Tags: angular, typescript, safari, html5-video, mobile-safari

I have been banging my head againest the wall trying to figure this issue out. Consistently safari will not play html videos despite adding all the properties older stack overflow posts have shown. I have tried programatically showing the videos, manually typing the videos in the HTML and still have the same issues. This is with the video as a `@ViewChild` although I have also tried it as a native element using raw JS to target with the same issue being presented. How do I autoplay videos in safari?!

#### Error I usually get when I promisify `video.play()`:

`Play failed AbortError: The operation was aborted.`

#### Formats:

- Videos are all confirmed to be encoded in mp4 with audio tracks that also are supported in Safari according tot heir docs.
- CDN the videos are stored on is a cloudfront CDN and does support Range GET requests

#### Versions I have tried (all with the same results):

```html
<!-- FAIL -->
<video
  #videoElement 
  preload="none" 
  [src]="src+'?ngsw-bypass=true'" 
  [muted]="true" 
  [playsInline]="true" 
  [autoplay]="true" 
  [loop]="true" 
  type="video/mp4">
</video>

<!-- FAIL -->
<video
  #videoElement 
  preload="none" 
  [src]="src" 
  [muted]="true" 
  [playsInline]="true" 
  [autoplay]="true" 
  [loop]="true" 
  type="video/mp4">
</video>

<!-- FAIL -->
<video 
  #videoElement 
  preload="none" 
  [src]="src" 
  muted 
  playsInline
  autoplay
  loop
  type="video/mp4">
</video>

<!-- FAIL -->
<video
  #videoElement 
  preload="none" 
  [src]="src" 
  muted 
  playsInline
  autoplay
  loop
  type="video/mp4">
</video>

<!-- FAIL -->
<video 
  #videoElement 
  preload="none" 
  muted 
  playsInline
  autoplay
  loop>
  <source [src]="src" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>

<!-- FAIL -->
<!-- Even tried assigning all properties via JS -->
<video 
  #videoElement 
  [src]="src" 
  type="video/mp4
>
</video>
```

#### TS Angular Component

```js
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video',
  templateUrl: './video.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video.component.scss'],
})
export class VideoComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('videoElement') video: ElementRef<HTMLVideoElement>;
  @Input() src: string = '';

  constructor() {}

  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.video) {
      try {
        this.video.nativeElement.autoplay = true;
        this.video.nativeElement.loop = true;
        this.video.nativeElement.muted = true;
        this.video.nativeElement.playsInline = true;
        this.video.nativeElement.play()
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error Playing', error);
      }
  }
}
```

#### Image of console error:

[image]

Comment: Is this on Mac or iOS and does the video play if you click on the controls? If you could share an example video and console logs that might help also. Great icon photo, btw!

Comment: This is in Mac Safari, and iOS Safari. The movie does not play with controls either in safari. However, intermittently the video will sometimes load. With apparently no bearing on my markup lol. Let me add a video to the original post.

Thanks re: profile image! That one isn't mine but I have a 1960 Mini I turbocharged. :-) I am on youtube too Classic Mini DIY.

Comment: Sounds like it might be something to do with the format of the video - if you could share an example vide that would likely help.